# Can HTML/PHP/Javascript code be commented in a single click/keycombination?

Tags: php, html, javascript, comments, aptana-studio

The question it's clear enough. I want to be able to select certain code and with a key combination or menu element be able to comment it in Aptana Studio 3. Yes, I can add the tags myself but I'd find faster to do it this way because when debugging I often need to comment code, uncomment it, comment it again,etc What I do now it's to delete the selected code, see what happens then un do it with Ctrl+Z, but I'd rather comment the code 'cause sometimes I do a mistake and can't undo and O can't recover the deleted code with an undo.

Can somebody please help me? THANKS! =)

Comment: This question has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961478/finding-shortcuts-in-aptana-studio-3-0-to-comment-code) on StackOverflow.

Comment: Try ctrl+7. This should work.

Comment: I'm sorry for repeating the question, I tried to search it first of course but I didn't find it! Maybe someone can delete this question or merge it or do what's done in these cases =) THANKS A LOT Ctrl+7 and Ctrl+Z will be my new favorite instead of Delete and Ctrl+Z THANKS !

Comment: are you open to some other editors??